# Redirect() Doesnt work after POST Submit with @csrf, keeps on reloading the page

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

i just started laravel and i am trying to create a simple post form for practive, when submitted it gives an 419 Error so I used @csrf inside the form.

**HTML Form:**

```
<form method="POST" action="/posts">
    @csrf
        <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Enter Title">
   
        <input type="submit" name="submit">

    </form>
```

**Route:**

```
Route::resource('/posts', 'PostController');
```

**Store Function:**

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
        $post = new Post;
        ...
        $post->save();
        return redirect('/posts'); //Tried
        return redirect()->route('posts.index'); 
    }
```

@csrf fixed the 419 error and made the post work.
The Post works only when there is no redirect(). I think the @csrf is making the redirect() not work.
I've been searching and couldn't find a solution. How do I fix this?

Comment: Welcome to SO ... what does "keeps on reloading the page" mean? .. if you are redirecting to the same URI you are already at it will look like its just reloaded

Comment: @lagbox It keeps on refreshing, so $post-save(); is done multilple times.

Comment: i dont know what you are talking about with it "keeps on refreshing"; you could create a redirect loop, but the browser refreshing is a browser issue of some sort

Comment: Refreshing or Loading?

Comment: @lagbox I think its the csrf doing the issue. Pretty sure redirect line is correct. However, when I remove redirect line, it works fine but I wanted to redirect to another page which is not letting me. Not a browser issue

Comment: @STA refreshing

Comment: Actually your queation is really unclear for me. redirect method is not related with csrf. Did you add `use Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse;` on the top?

Answer (score 0):

make `action="{{ route('posts.store') }}"` instead of `action="/posts"`

make `return redirect()->route('posts.index')`;

Comment: Can i see your last Store Function?

Comment: ```
 public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
        $post = new Post;
        $post->user_id = 1;
        $post->title = $request->title;
        $post->content = 'Test content';
        $post->save();
        return redirect()->route('posts.create');
    }
```

Comment: wdym last store function? The Store function is above.

Comment: btw, the page refreshes after redirect()->route('....'). You can use Ajax to avoid page refresh.